# Not able to run the Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Build was successful but when I tried to run the project using AVD, it shows the following message. I'm not sure what went wrong.

> Warning: No DNS servers found
>
> emulator: device fd:608
>
> HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
>
> emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in
>   your HAXM configuration.
>
> emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB
>
> emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB
>
> emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM
>   configuration to run in fast virt mode.
>
> creating window 43 59 329 583 emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version
>   check

Comment: Try installing HAMX https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Comment: when you create your emulator then set its RAM size as <= 512MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust your adb ram size.

First open android studio.Then at the top icon bar you can find this [image: adb_icon] icon.Click it.This will open all available virtual device you have.Select your virtual device and at the right you can find this icon [image: edit_icon].Click it.This will open a new window.At the bottom of this window you can find this [image].Click it.Then there will be a section like this [image: section].Then change RAM size 1536 to 512.Like this [image: edit_ram_size].Now click finish and run your application.

Edit:

If your target api is upper than 19 then you need to adjust your haxm installer ram size because when you run your app the avd ram size will increase to 1 GB.
So how to adjust your haxm installer ram size.Follow the step mentioned below.

If you install android studio by it's default position then you can find haxm installer in this locaiton
'C:\Users\Niyamat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager'

Go to this location(make sure you change userName Niyamat to your username).Click "intelhaxm-android" and run it.Then an alert dialog pop up like this [image] click yes.Then click Next.And finally click Set manually.and remove 512 and add 1024.Something like this [image].Then click next then install.Wait few seconds for install.And that's it.I think now you can run your app on your virtual device.
Hope this help!

Comment: still a little trouble, as follows                                                                                                                          C:\Android\AndroidSDK\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Mohanas_Android
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
Warning: No DNS servers found
emulator: device fd:620
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 0 0 411 729
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check

Comment: Can you please post your PC configuration.

Comment: Okay, if your PC configuration is good then you can follow my answer(I update it).

Comment: Niyamat, done it, but you know the problem is Emulator is showing up now, but with a blank screen. Not sure what exactly is happening. I did the AVD tweak, then the HAXM tweak but still no hope. But if i run the same project using a device(USB connected) it is working.

Comment: Niyamat, thanks for all the time, yes it is working now.

Comment: I am also happy for helping you

Answer (score 1):

HAXM RAM size should be more than AVD. 
Better decrease the RAM size of AVD by editing the emulated device or the other way increase HAXM RAM size.

Comment: how to exactly do that? I mean give specific location.

Comment: @SandeepRoy Go to your avd manager. Delete the emulator and create a new one. However for the new one make sure it's ram is less than 512 mb.

Answer (score 1):

HAXM RAM size should be more than AVD. Decrease the RAM size of AVD or increase HAXM RAM size.

To reduce ram of avd (Wich I recommend)

Go to your avd manager. Delete the emulator and create a new one. However for the new one make sure it's ram is less than 512 mb.